# Как выбрать в датафрейме только те строки, которые содержаться в другом датафрейме?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

У меня есть два датафрейма. В одном юзеры, у которых ARPU как раз такой, который мне нужен.
В другом все заказы, где у каждого заказа есть уникальный id- юзера и тд.
Как мне получить второй датафрейм, где id юзеров будут только те, которые есть в первом фрейме.
Это первый датафрейм Users.

```
     user_id   avg      
0     158     56,76   
1     529     89,90         
2     300     59,43  
3     481     90,34      
4     450     23,56      
5     860     67,98     
5     230     89,88
```

Это второй датафрейм df.

```
     user_id   price      
0     158     330   
1     529     540          
2     481     120      
4     22      45      
5     69      87     
5     10      90
6     158     190
```

Я ожидаю такой датафрейм, который будет содержать все строки датафрейма df, но и id только тех пользователей, которые содержаться в датафрейме Users.

```
     user_id   price      
0     158     330   
1     529     540         
2     481     120      
3     158     190
```

Я использовал is in, но он как то криво работает и не выводит то, что мне нужно.

Comment: Как вы использовали `isin`? Должно работать. Только нужно использовать пандасовский

Answer (score 0):

Должно работать как-то так:

```py
selected = users[userd['user_id'].isin(df['user_id'])]
```

Если вдруг не будет работать, то нужно попробовать взять от `df['user_id']` либо `.to_list()` либо `.values`, возможно если в `isin` используется `Series`, то оно ещё индексы на совпадение проверяет. Но может и нет.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, это типичная задачка для `merge`:

```
Users = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [158, 529, 300, 481, 450, 860, 230], 'avg': ['56,76', '89,90', '59,43', '90,34', '23,56', '67,98', '89,88']}, index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5])
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [158, 529, 481, 22, 69, 10, 158], 'price': [330, 540, 120, 45, 87, 90, 190]}, index=[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6])
df = Users.merge(df)[df.columns]
print(df)
```

```
   user_id  price
0      158    330
1      158    190
2      529    540
3      481    120
```